# Pandas: fillna not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a lot of NAN values:

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

df looks like:

```
x001    x002    x003    x004    x005    x006    x007    x008    x009    x010    ... x296    x297    x298    x299    x300    x301    x302    x303    x304    y
0   1540332 NaN NaN NaN 8.0 1   0   1   0   0   ... 0   NaN 0   0   0   0   NaN 0   NaN 706
```

When I do the following:

```
df2 = df.fillna(lambda x: df.median())
```

df2 looks like:

```
x001    x002    x003    x004    x005    x006    x007    x008    x009    x010    ... x296    x297    x298    x299    x300    x301    x302    x303    x304    y
0   1540332 <function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>  <function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>  <function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>  8   1   0   1   0   0   ... 0   <function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>  0   0   0   0   <function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>  0   <function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>  706
 1  823066  4
```

I am not able to figure out why instead of replacing the NAN values with the median, I see `<function <lambda> at 0x110b48488>`

p.s I tried mean as well, but same results.

Comment: Why not `df.fillna(df.median())`?

Comment: df.fillna(lambda x: df.mean()) return a new dataframe, with the same output

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lambda function.

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```